# Variável Global com TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, variáveis, script, variáveis-globais

Então... estou fazendo um código em TypeScript em que eu preciso usar uma variável de outro script, vou deixar mais claro abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var global = "Variável Global";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/file.js"></script>
```

E dentro do file.js eu preciso capturar essa variavel, alguém me ajuda ?

Exemplo:

file.js:

```
window.onload = function () {
     alert(global);
}
```

Comment: `(window as any).global` funciona?

Comment: onde eu deveria colocar isso ? @LuizFelipe

Comment: Ao acessar a variável global. Aliás, edite a sua pergunta, postando o código em que você tenta acessar a variável global para que eu tenha um pouco mais de contexto.

Comment: Então seria assim `alert(window!.global);`? @user140828

Comment: @LuizFelipe, o código é basicamente isso aí mesmo, quando a pagina carregar, ele da o alert da variavel

Comment: Você tentou `alert((window as any).variavelGlobalAqui)`?

Comment: Você pode usar `declare var global: tipo`.

Comment: Funcionou @LuizFelipe, muito obrigado... poderia responder à pergunta para as pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida futuramente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De forma simples, você pode acessar variáveis globais assim:

```js
const globalVariable = (window as any).globalVariable
```

Por exemplo:

```js
alert((window as any).globalVariable)
```

Comment: Funcionou como esperado, muito obrigado